# Android - how to force Chrome browser to download file instead of passing it to Download manager

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, download, http-headers

First of all, I would like to clarify that I'm not an Android device user, I'm a web developer.

Secondly, I tried searching around internet and consult other questions, but they didn't help.
My problem is: In my page, I want user to download a `.pdf` file by using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleDownload() {
    window.location.replace('./link/to/file.pdf');
  }
</script>
```

When user clicks on 'Download' button, `handleDownload()` is trigger, it's OK on Windows browsers like Firefox, Chrome, but for Chrome on Android, it opens the link by Android Download manager.

The problem is that Android Download manager doesn't have same session ID with Chrome, thus it is not logged in, and failed to download `.pdf` file.
When I try to download a `.pdf` file from Google Drive, it is downloaded by Chrome, not the Download Manager, so I believe there is a way (probably a special HTTP header) to do this.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that problem is caused by my user use a external download manager (ESDownloadManager). After he uninstalled this app, the Session problem's gone.

Have a nice day all.